# White Background Flickering

Tags: jquery

Fiddling since hours with this jquery script here:

http://www.graphicbeacon.com/web-design-development/how-to-create-a-background-scrolling-effect-with-jquery/

in order to get rid of the white background of the images appearing between page loads since I'm using it as background image effect of a site.

Using two .png images and set the background color with css to transparent and added additionally a fadeIn effect.

In FF and Opera I can't see the flickering but in IE, Chrome and Safari when switching between pages.

I'm sure there is a (probably simple) solution for this out here, but I'm just not able to find it or figure it out myself.

Additionally I'd like to know, whether it is possible, that the script does not need to be loaded on each page load, i.e. the script should keep on running when switching between pages?

Anybody out there who's got any advice for me, please? Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with the test case?

Comment: @insertusernamehere - here you go [jsfiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/DdtSa/)

Answer (score 0):

I created a local copy with some links and can see what you mea. On page reload or when calling another link it shortly refreshes the content. This happens on my computer in every browser. I tested it in Safari 6, Chrome 24 and Firefox 18. This is something you can't solve as the content is newly rendered every time. But you're gonna solve it with your additional question on how to not re-start the animation on every page load.

When you want the animation to keep running and you want to switch the content of the page use **AJAX**. AJAX lets you send a request and get a response without the need to refresh the whole page. An example:

**HML**

```
<!-- div that holds the content - use this in addition to your background divs -->
<div id="content"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    // the page with the content, you could use a HTML file for every section on your page
    url: "content.html",
    cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
        // .done() handles the response, this time we replace the content of our div
        $("#content").html(html);
});
```

**content.html**

```
<!-- can be any valid HTML and JavaScript -->
<p>Hey, this is nice</p>
```

**Resumé**

Using this your animation will keep running, no flashing when re-rendering the page and you can load all content you want.

**Read more**

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Note**

The script you're using caused some computing on my Intel Core Duo i5 from 2010 and it was lagging from time to time. You can improve the overall performance by using [CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) on modern browsers. It will use less CPU as it doesnt't have to execute a lot of JavaScript and will look smoother.

Also the script is using `eval`. Read this [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to get an idea and try to re-write the part that is using it. I guess it can be done easily (I didn't look that deep into the code).

I hope this helps you and results in a nice solution on your side.